# Pyqt5 label in plot widget prevents scrolling

Tags: python, plot, scroll, pyqt5, label

Im using Pyqt5 to create a plotter to show measured data. I have added a label to the plotter to inform the user when the plotter is not recording the data.
I have enabled mouse scrolling for the plot widget to allow the user to scroll the Y-axis.

Unfortunalty the label location prevents the user from scrolling the Y-axis.

Ive tried reading the pyqt documentation and google my question but I could not find the right answer, maybe adding the label to the plot widget is an incorrect way to show text in a plot widget but I could not find a better way.

How can I change the label or plot widget properties to allow scrolling when the mouse is hovering over the label? Or is it possible to add the text to the plot widget without using the label?
[image: My plotter and label]

Example code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.plot_widget.setGeometry(100, 120, 600, 200)
        self.plot_widget.plot(y=np.random.normal(size=200))
        self.plot_widget.setTitle("Basic array plotting")
        self.PlotWindowLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        pos = 0.5 * self.PlotWindowLabel.parent().rect().bottomRight() - 0.5 * self.PlotWindowLabel.rect().bottomRight()
        self.PlotWindowLabel.move(pos)
        self.PlotWindowLabel.setText('Basic text for label')
        self.PlotWindowLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 40pt; color:rgba(226, 39, 134, 127)}")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Kind regards

Comment: Probably a focus problem, but you have to provide us a [mre] for a proper answer.

Comment: I have added it in my original post. Excuse me for not adding it.

Comment: Use `self.PlotWindowLabel.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)`. Note that you should probably consider pyqtgraph's [TextItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/textitem.html).

Comment: Thank you musicamante, your answer helped me. Now I have to figure out how to mark your answer as correct.